# Quartz .Net - Meaning of BigInt DateTime

Tags: t-sql, quartz.net

we've used sql server as our persisted data store for Quartz.net.  I'd like to write some queries looking @ the Time values.  Specifically - Qrtz_Fired_Triggers.Fired_Time, Qrtz_Triggers.Next_fire_time, Prev_fire_time.

For the life of me, I can't find anything that says what this data is - ticks, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds.  I've guessed at a couple of things, but they've all proven wrong.

The best answer would include the math to convert the big int into a datetime and perhaps even a link(s) to the pages/documentation that I should have found - explaining the meaning of the data in those fields.

If you have specific instructions on using Quartz .Net libraries to view this information, that would be appreciated, but, I really have 2 goals - to understand the meaning of the date/time data being stored and to keep this in T-SQL.  If I get the one, I can figure out T-SQL or out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value stored in database is the DateTime.Ticks value. From MSDN:

> A single tick represents one hundred
>   nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a
>   second. There are 10,000 ticks in a
>   millisecond.
>
> The value of this property represents
>   the number of 100-nanosecond intervals
>   that have elapsed since 12:00:00
>   midnight, January 1, 0001, which
>   represents DateTime.MinValue. It does
>   not include the number of ticks that
>   are attributable to leap seconds.

Comment: The question is not "What is Datetime.Ticks?"  The question is - in Quartz.net, when a date / time is stored as a big int, what is the meaning of that data?

Comment: The meaning depends on the context. It's usually the start time of trigger, the end time of trigger or last fire time. Column name should reveal the intention on a column basis.

Comment: Please accept my apologies.  I replied in haste, managing to skip straight to "From MSDN:".  Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: No worries, glad that I could help.

Answer (score 43):

On the SQL side, you can convert from Quartz.NET BIGINT times to a DateTime in UTC time with:

```
SELECT CAST(NEXT_FIRE_TIME/864000000000.0 - 693595.0 AS DATETIME) FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS
```

### Numbers Explanation

Values stored in the column are the number of ticks from .NET `DateTime.MinValue` in UTC time.  There are 10000 ticks per millisecond.

The `864000000000.0` represents the number of ticks in a single day.  You can verify this with

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,'19000101','19000102')*10000.0
```

Now, if we take March 13, 2013 at midnight, .NET returns `634987296000000000` as the number of ticks.

```
var ticks = new DateTime(2013, 3, 13).Ticks;
```

To get a floating point number where whole numbers represent days and decimal numbers represent time, we take the ticks and divide by the number of ticks per day (giving us `734939.0` in our example)

```
SELECT 634987296000000000/(DATEDIFF(ms,'19000101','19000102')*10000.0)
```

If we get put the date in SQL and convert to a float, we get a different number: `41344.0`

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('March 13, 2013 0:00' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT)
```

So, we need to generate a conversion factor for the .NET-to-SQL days.  SQL minimum date is January 1, 1900 0:00, so the correction factor can be calculated by taking the number of ticks for that time (`599266080000000000`) and dividing by the ticks per day, giving us `693595.0`

```
SELECT 599266080000000000/(DATEDIFF(ms,'19000101','19000102')*10000.0)
```

So, to calculate the DateTime of a Quartz.NET date:

- take the value in the column
- divide by the number of ticks per day
- subtract out the correction factor
- convert to a DATETIME

```
SELECT CAST([Column]/864000000000.0 - 693595.0 AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I tried this out and got a difference of exactly 2 hours. I think i need to add +2h Time shift from UTC base time.

Comment: @had Yes, if you are UTC+2, then you would need to add 2 hours to the results of the function to get the time in your local time zone.

Comment: @saluce In my test using flaot the calculation causes miliseconds differences, maybe roundoff error, e.g. 8:30:00,000 is represented as 08:29:59.997. Taking out the float part gives the exact time! What am I missing?

Comment: @natenho Yes, doing `SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST('March 13, 2013 8:30' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) AS DATETIME)` generates a tiny rounding error, and 0:59.997 is SQL Server's approximation of 1 millisecond below 1:00.000.  SQL Server doesn't record exact milliseconds, it actually uses 1/300th of a second (3.33 millisecond) accuracy for [DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28SQL.80%29.aspx), hence the loss of 3 milliseconds due to rounding errors.

Comment: This post is old but I just want to say this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, unless I missed something and am making this too complicated, I couldn't get the dateadd functions in Ms Sql Server 2008 to handle such large values and I kept getting overflow errors.  The approach I took in Ms Sql Server was this:
a) find a date closer to now than 0001.01.01 & its ticks value
b) use a function to give me a DateTime value.

Notes:
* for my application - seconds was good enough.
* I've not tested this extensively, but so far, it has acted pretty well for me.

The function:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[net_ticks_to_date_time]
   (
      @net_ticks BIGINT
   )
   RETURNS DATETIME
   AS
   BEGIN

      DECLARE 
         @dt_2010_11_01 AS DATETIME = '2010-11-01'
      ,  @bi_ticks_for_2010_11_01 AS BIGINT = 634241664000000000
      ,  @bi_ticks_in_a_second AS BIGINT = 10000000

      RETURN
         (
            DATEADD(SECOND , ( ( @net_ticks - @bi_ticks_for_2010_11_01 ) / @bi_ticks_in_a_second ) , @dt_2010_11_01)
         );

   END
  GO
```

### Here is how I came up with the # of ticks to some recent date:

```
DECLARE 
   @dt2_dot_net_min AS DATETIME2 = '01/01/0001'
   , @dt2_first_date AS DATETIME2
   , @dt2_next_date AS DATETIME2
   , @bi_seconds_since_0101001 BIGINT = 0


   SET @dt2_first_date = @dt2_dot_net_min;

   SET @dt2_next_date = DATEADD ( DAY, 1, @dt2_first_date )



WHILE ( @dt2_first_date < '11/01/2010' )
   BEGIN
      SELECT @bi_seconds_since_0101001 = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @dt2_first_date, @dt2_next_date ) + @bi_seconds_since_0101001

      PRINT 'seconds 01/01/0001 to ' + CONVERT ( VARCHAR, @dt2_next_date,  101) + ' = ' + CONVERT ( VARCHAR, CAST ( @bi_seconds_since_0101001 AS MONEY ), 1)

      SET @dt2_first_date = DATEADD ( DAY, 1, @dt2_first_date );
      SET @dt2_next_date = DATEADD ( DAY, 1, @dt2_first_date )      

   END
```

Comment: Or, to get ticks for a date in C#: `new DateTime(2010, 11, 01).Ticks` which gives 634241664000000000

Answer (score 0):

If you are with Quartz .Net and Postgress use this.

> The value stored in database is the DateTime.Ticks value

```
Select  to_timestamp(((NEXT_FIRE_TIME  - 621355968000000000) / 10000000)) FROM  qrtz_triggers
```